# How do I test ActiveRecord references in Cucumber?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, cucumber

I am trying to create some cucumber features with references to other objects. I am running into some problems when I want to create relationships between objects and run tests on them. I haven't found any samples anywhere else.

Let's say I have the following models:

```
class Athlete < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :shoe_size
  validates_presence_of :first_name
  validates_presence_of :last_name
  validates_presence_of :shoe_size_id
end
```

And

```
class Shoe_Size < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

That correspond to

```
create_table :athlete do |t|
  t.string :first_name
  t.string :last_name
  t.references :shoe_size
end
```

And

```
create_table :shoe_size do |t|
  t.string :size
  t.integer :sort_order
end
```

In Cucumber, I might create the following feature:

```
Scenario: Follow the edit link from the athlete list
    Given the following shoe sizes
          | size | sort_order |
          | 10   | 1          |
          | 10.5 | 2          |
          | 11   | 3          |
      And the following athlete
          | first_name | last_name | size |
          | John       | Doe       | 10.5 |
      And I am on the list page
     When I follow "edit"
     Then I should be on the edit page
```

I'd like to be able to give data like "Size" because I don't know the :id of the shoe sizes created in the first given. Is this the right approach to the problem? Should I do something else?

How do I set up my step definition to do this? I tried something like the following, but it is nowhere close.

```
Given /^the following athlete$/ do |table|
  table.hashes.each do |hash|
    shoe_size = hash[:shoe_size]
    hash.delete(:shoe_size)
    hash[:shoe_size_id] = Radius.find(:size => radius_size).id
    athlete.create(hash)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Given /^the following athlete$/ do |table|
  table.hashes.each do |hash|
    Athlete.create(:first_name => hash[:first_name],
      :last_name => hash[:last_name]
      :shoe_size => ShoeSize.find_by_size(hash[:size])
  end
end
```

ought to work, although you might want to look at using fixtures or factories if you don't really need to describe the model attributes in the scenario. [Factory Girl](http://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) might be a good fit.

Comment: what if there's a table Athelte but cucumber error is Could not find table athletes?

Comment: @Sergey `rake db:test:prepare`